# Why I can not make it tag in the curved line?

Tags: html, css, svg

I m trying to make in curved link two different type of fonts, but it is not possible, because of i cant make it tag here. Is any solution how to do this?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
  <text width="500">
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
      Im trying make it with span <span>THIS</span>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an SVG `<tspan>` element, not an HTML `<span>` element here.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
  <text width="500">
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
      Im trying make it with span <tspan font-family="sans-serif">THIS</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```